# PL/SQL returning Procedure value and putting it in an insert clause

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert, plsql

I'm doing an assignment and the last question states that I call the procedure from question 2 and function from question 3 and then put them in an insert clause(question 4).

> 4. Write a PL/SQL Code for an anonymous block to do the following:
>
> a) Get the doctor name for a given doctor id (read from keyboard) using a procedure [ProGetDoctorName].
>
> b) Get the department name for a given department id (read from keyboard) using a function [FunGetDepartmentName].
>
> c) Insert the doctor name and department name (which you got from the procedure and
> function) by including serial number and current date into the visitings table"

---

The tables and records

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT(
DeptNo      NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
DeptName    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE DOCTORS(
DoctorID    NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
DoctorNAME  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
DeptNo      NUMBER(4) REFERENCES DEPT(DEPTNO),
Salary      NUMBER(8) NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE VISITINGS(
SlNo        NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
DoctorName  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
DepartmentName  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
VisitDate   DATE NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(10,'ENT');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(20,'Orthopedic');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(30,'Cardiology');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(40,'Neurology');

INSERT INTO DOCTORS VALUES(101,'Abheer',20,2550);
INSERT INTO DOCTORS VALUES(102,'Zuwaina',10,2175);
INSERT INTO DOCTORS VALUES(103,'Sara',30,1985);
INSERT INTO DOCTORS VALUES(104,'Fatma',20,2200);
INSERT INTO DOCTORS VALUES(105,'Laila',10,2600);


INSERT INTO VISITINGS VALUES(1,'Sara','Cardiology','10-Nov-19');
INSERT INTO VISITINGS VALUES(2,'Abheer','Orthopedic','11-Nov-19');
```

---

My Procedure

```
create or replace procedure ProGetDoctorName(a in number, b out varchar2) is
docname doctors.doctorname%type;
Begin
select doctorname into docname from doctors where doctorid=a;
dbms_output.put_line('Doctor Name: '||docname);
End
```

---

My Function

```
create or replace function FunGetDepartmentName(deptid in number) return varchar2 is
dname dept.deptname%type;
Begin
select deptname into dname from dept where DeptNo=deptid;
return dname;
End
```

---

Question 4 Answer where I call and insert

```
Declare
docname varchar2(50);
depname varchar2(50);
serial number;
Begin
ProGetDoctorName(:Docid,docname);
depname:=FunGetDepartmentName(:DeptNo);
dbms_output.put_line('Department Name: '||depname);
select count(slno) into serial from visitings;
serial :=serial+1;
insert into visitings(slno,doctorname,departmentname,visitdate) values(serial,docname,depname,sysdate);
End
```

---

I keep getting "can't insert null into ("XX"."VISITINGS"."DOCTORNAME")"

Tried different variations to insert but didn't work even without the dbms in procedure. Tried it without the procedure in insert. Worked. I've read that it's not possible to take the return value of a procedure and use it in something.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You don't actually return anything from `ProGetDoctorName` Also, the way you derive new serial numbers `serial :=serial+1;` is a Very Bad Idea™️; use a sequence instead.

Comment: You have a bug in your procedure.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to find it.  Hint: Unit Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hints. I solved the answer by assigning the docname to the out variable in my procedure.

My procedure

```
create or replace procedure ProGetDoctorName(a in number, b out varchar2) is
docname doctors.doctorname%type;
Begin
select doctorname into docname from doctors where doctorid=a;
dbms_output.put_line('Doctor Name: '||docname);
b:=docname;
End
```